# Tomcat HTTP Status 403 - Evaluation of...did not complete within the allowed time limit

Tags: tomcat, timeout, wolfram-mathematica

I'm developing a web application with webMathematica and using Apache Tomcat 7.0.57 as a server.
I've developed a GUI in a .jsp-File with text fields, drop down menus and radio buttons where the user can enter specific information and select preferences for the calculations. The Mathematica kernel is running the calculations on Tomcat. When I click the button to send the form and do the calculations, I get the following error after aoout 30 seconds of waiting:

HTTP Status 403 - Evaluation of ...(the code I wrote)... did not complete within the allowed time limit

The calculations are quite long and even take a while to complete using Mathematica. I tried increasing the connectionTimeout from 20000 to 600000 in the server.xml file to allow more time for a responce, but it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if this is the correct setting to change in this case?

Does anybody have an idea how to work around this issue or another way to increase the timeout limit?

Thanks!

---

Sample Code:

MSPShow[

ContourPlot[(1 - (1/(10^y))*(10^x)^0.7*constL)/(1 + (2.*Pi*(10^y)/10^x*constR)), {x, -10, 30}, {y, -10, 20}, Mesh -> None, Contours -> Range[.2, 1, .2], ContourLabels -> All, ContourShading -> None,    FrameLabel -> {" SP. PRESSURE" HoldForm[Subscript["[CapitalDelta]p", "+"]] , "REYNOLDS NUMBER RE"}, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 22, Italic]],

Graphics[{Hue[deltaeta], PointSize[Large], Point[{{Log[10, PPLUSbp], Log[10, REbp]}}]}]

]

I am trying to plot a contour plot and a point that changes color depending on the value of a variable in the same graph. It worked fine in Mathematica using Show[].

---

More Code:

```
n = 800/60;
nu = 0.86/10^6;
deltap = 5*10^5;
roh = 1000;
Vn = 8/1000;
MR0 = 10^-1;
So0 = 10^6;
QL0 = 10^1;
P0 = 10^7.8;
constL = QL0/(P0)^(0.7);
constR = MR0/(So0)^(-1);
 REbp = n*Vn^(2/3)/nu;
PPLUSbp = deltap/(nu^2*roh*Vn^(-2/3));
etagesmodell = (1 - (1/REbp)*PPLUSbp^0.7*constL)/(1 + 
 2*Pi*REbp/PPLUSbp*constR);
Q = 10/3600;
Ps = 70*10^3;
etagesref = Q/(n*Vn)*(deltap*Vn/(Ps/n));
deltaeta = Abs[(1 - (etagesmodell/etagesref))];
Show[
 ContourPlot[(1 - (1/(10^y))*(10^x)^0.7*constL)/(1 + (2.*Pi*(10^y)/10^x*constR)), {x, -10, 30}, {y, -10, 20}, Mesh -> None,   Contours -> Range[.2, 1, .2], ContourLabels -> All,   ContourShading -> None, FrameLabel -> {"SP. PRESSURE" HoldForm[Subscript["\[CapitalDelta]p", "+"]] , "REYNOLDS NUMBER RE"},   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 22, Italic]],
 Graphics[{Hue[deltaeta], PointSize[Large],Point[{{Log[10, PPLUSbp], Log[10, REbp]}}]}]
]
```

This is what I'm trying to reproduce in webMathematica. Like I said, it works in Mathematica. I'm using Mathematica 9.0 on Windows 8.1. The values at the beginning (n, nu,...etc.) are entered by the user through text fields on the web page. Depending on further preferences that can be selected through checkboxes and drop down menus, different calculations are executed before plotting - so this is just one of the cases.

Comment: Why don't you accelerate your calculation? Otherwise you have to edit the WEB-INF/MSPConfiguration.xml file, see also: http://reference.wolfram.com/webMathematica/ref/config/KernelTimeLimit.html

Comment: I accelerated it by changing the function. The calculation is really fast now.
However, I'm getting the following error now where a graph should be loaded:   
2
Null  MSPShow[-Graphics-, -Graphics-]

Comment: Please post a minimal code example, then we can have a look.

Comment: @RolfMertig I posted some sample code in my original post, it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Please add definitions such that I could run your code. Which Mathematica version are you using? Which operating system?

Comment: @RolfMertig I added some more code to my original post. If you run it in Mathematica, you should be able to see the graph I'm trying to get in webMathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I would  use Epilog. Then, this jsp page works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.wolfram.com/msp" prefix="msp" %>
${msp:initializePage(pageContext)}
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">
<h1>test for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306027/tomcat-http-status-403-evaluation-of-did-not-complete-within-the-allowe                             d-tim?noredirect=1#comment48931148_30306027 </h1>
</div>
<form action="<%= request.getRequestURI() %> "method="post">
<msp:evaluate> DateString[] </msp:evaluate>
<h2> graphics </h2>
<msp:evaluate>
n = 800/60;
nu = 0.86/10^6;
deltap = 5*10^5;
roh = 1000;
Vn = 8/1000;
MR0 = 10^-1;
So0 = 10^6;
QL0 = 10^1;
P0 = 10^7.8;
constL = QL0/(P0)^(0.7);
constR = MR0/(So0)^(-1);
 REbp = n*Vn^(2/3)/nu;
PPLUSbp = deltap/(nu^2*roh*Vn^(-2/3));
etagesmodell = (1 - (1/REbp)*PPLUSbp^0.7*constL)/(1 +
 2*Pi*REbp/PPLUSbp*constR);
Q = 10/3600;
Ps = 70*10^3;
etagesref = Q/(n*Vn)*(deltap*Vn/(Ps/n));
deltaeta = Abs[(1 - (etagesmodell/etagesref))];
MSPShow[
ContourPlot[(1 - (1/(10^y))*(10^x)^0.7*
      constL)/(1 + (2.*Pi*(10^y)/10^x*constR)), {x, -10, 30}, {y, -10,
    20}, Mesh -> None, Contours -> Range[.2, 1, .2],
  ContourLabels -> All, ContourShading -> None,
  FrameLabel -> {"SP. PRESSURE" HoldForm[
      Subscript["\[CapitalDelta]p", "+"]], "REYNOLDS NUMBER RE"},
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 22, Italic],
  Epilog -> {Hue[deltaeta], PointSize[Large],
    Point[{{Log[10, PPLUSbp], Log[10, REbp]}}]}
]
]
</msp:evaluate>
</form> </body> </html>
```

Comment: This jsp also worked for me, thank you. However, when I implemented the graphics part into my jsp and loaded it I got the message:
  
<img\
>    src='/webMathematica/MSP/MSP31i3847icc7bgd35800003g76135c6e07dc93?MSPSto\
>    reType=image/gif' alt='created by webMathematica' />

Comment: I'm guessing this is an error somewhere in my jsp. Do you know of any good webMathematica examples that I could use as a guide? Something with text fields, radiobuttons, drop down menus, plotting functions and how to pass variables from text fields. Also how to properly write if-statements with passed variables. The examples on the Wolfram site didn't help me too much.

Comment: Just look at the documentation and try the examples. webMathematica programming takes some time to learn.